# @angular - Defualt/NoPreloading strategy opens blank page, component is not initialized at all

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

Preloading routes using default route strategy or NoPreloadingStrategy changes the url but do not initialize the component at all (the page is blank).

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'cart', canActivate: [CartGuardService], component: CartComponent },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/cart', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**login-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', canActivate: [LoginGuardService], component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { }
```

in my **app.component.html** button click navigates to login url using.

```
this.router.navigate(['/login'])
```

in login.component.ts neither **constructor** or **ngOnInit** is called, have placed *console.log* in both of them, nothing in console gets printed, the url in the address bar is changed but it opens blank page.

**ng --version**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.0.0
@angular/compiler: 4.0.0
@angular/core: 4.0.0
@angular/forms: 4.0.0
@angular/http: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.0
@angular/router: 4.0.0
@angular/animations: 4.0.0
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the guards. Am sure the `CartGuardService` redirects to the login if the user has not login.

If it does successfully navigate to the login then nothing happens then the issue is coming from the `LoginGuardService`.

Are you not using an observable that doesn't close?

Comment: removed all route guards, but still the same problem. @phacic